# Can C# async/await be used without a large amount of heap allocation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to use async/await in the context of a game engine where high framerate is important and garbage collection halts should be avoided.  Idiomatic async/await appears to rely heavily on heap allocation.  How can I reduce this?

`Task<T>s` allocate on the heap, await appears to cause allocations, and task cancellation through `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` generate a large stacktrace.  In fact, [it appears](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled?view=netframework-4.8) that there is no way to cancel a task without allocating an exception and stack trace.

I could implement task cancellation like so but it seems counter intuitive to not use IsCancelled.

```
public async Task<T> Method<T>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Do not do this as it could cause a TaskCanceledException
    //await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);  

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //perhaps return null to show a cancellation?
        return default;
    }

    //uncancelled work...

}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: .net core has introduced a `ValueTask`, but that probably doesn't help with unity.

Comment: I think unity supports coroutines by abusing generator functions. But that can still create memory allocations.

Comment: https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask is an excellent library for high-performance C# async, written specifically with Unity3D in mind. All the allocations happen on startup and are pooled for re-use thereafter. It has allowed us to greatly simplify all sorts of logic in our game!